# Grouping in TreeListView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview, treelistview

I use the component `TreeListView` from [`ObjectListView`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/cookbook.htm) by Phillip Piper.

I want tree view with groups, but groups do not creating.

Somebody can me help with it?

I want it:

```
|        Column 1       | Column 2 | Column 3 |

== Group 1 [2 items] ===========================
   + Item 1             | Value 1  | Value 2  |
     Item 2             | Value 1  | Value 2  |
   - Item 3             | Value 1  | Value 2  |
       Sub Item 1       | Value 1  | Value 2  |
       Sub Item 2       | Value 1  | Value 2  |

== Group 2 [N items] ===========================
   + Item 1             | Value 1  | Value 2  |
   ...
```

**UPDATE:**

My model

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Gettter for get aspect foreach row object

```cs
olvColumnName.AspectGetter = delegate (object rowObject)
{
    if (rowObject is Model model)
        return model.Name;
    else if (rowObject is int numb)
        return numb.ToString();
    return null;
}
```

Group key getter

```cs
olvColumnType.GroupKeyGetter = delegate (object rowObject)
{
    if (rowObject is Model model)
        return model.Type;
    return null;
}
```

Check expand

```cs
treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate (object rowObject)
{
    if (rowObject is Model model)
        return model.Items != null && model.Items.Length > 0;
    return false;
};
```

Get expand children

```cs
treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate (object rowObject)
{
   if (rowObject is Model model)
      return model.Items;
   return null;
};
```

**UPDATE:**

I found that for the `TreeListView` component not defined `GroupingStrategy` property and did override `CanShowGroups` property which always return `false`.

So i think the component has properties, inherit from `ObjectListView`, but it not use they, and this mode not support.

Comment: Look into the **grouping** section of http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/getting-started.htm and try to implement the `GroupKeyGetter` delegate.

Comment: @JAlex, it not helped, i implemented the `GroupKeyGetter`, set `ShowGroups` to `true`, and call `BuildGroups` method, but it not got result, the list dont display items and groups.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried in [the minimum code needed to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem.

Comment: @JAlex, this my [test project](https://yadi.sk/d/bb6ShsQV_BIQTw), but here other problem, when i try set `ShowGroups` to `true` hapend a `NullReferenceException`, i cant find a reason

Comment: Windson, pleas [edit] the question to add these necessary details in order for people to answer this question. Comments isn't the place for updates to the question.